# WPF Dockable Windows Like iGoogle

Tags: wpf, controls, wpf-controls, docking, igoogle

I'm looking for a dockable windows/panel control in the style of [iGoogle](http://www.google.co.uk/ig?hl=en&source=iglk). All of the ones I have found so far all have a fixed length on the height of your window/panel but I want to be able to have windows of varying length like iGoogle.

The best I have found so far has been a control libarary called BlackLight which does not have the feature explained above.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this docking library:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFdockinglib.aspx

Comment: That control is more of a Visual Studio style docking control which is not what I'm looking for. Take a look at the BlackLight website for a really good example http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/.

Comment: Thats more of a Visual Studio style docking library. Take a look a BlackLight which is more what I'm after: http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/